# Centering children of tikz tree layout

Tags: tikz-trees

How do I force the middle child of a tikz `tree layout` to be vertically aligned with its parent?  For example, in the following code, the middle child of the root node is noticeably to the left of the center of the root node.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tree layout]
\tikzset{sibling distance=0em}
\tikzset{sibling sep=0em}
\node {$+$}
 child {node{$+$}
  child {node{$Exp$}}
  child {node{$+$}}
  child {node{$Exp$}}
 }
 child {node{$+$}}
 child {node{$Exp$}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that the problem goes away if I don't set `sibling distance` and `sibling sep` to `0em`, but I need those to get some of the larger diagrams to fit in the context of my document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are prepared to use the specialist tree drawing package, Forest, then you can achieve a high degree of flexibility and control over the output.

In addition to allowing a high degree of control and supporting powerful automation options, Forest also permits very concise specifications of trees. In this case, the tree itself is given by

```
 [+[+[Exp][+][Exp]][+][Exp]]
```

although

```
  [+
    [+
      [Exp]
      [+]
      [Exp]
    ]
    [+]
    [Exp]
  ]
```

is a lot easier for a human to read since it reflects the tree's structure spatially.

For example,

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    math content,
    s sep=0pt,
    text height/.pgfmath={height("Xpy")},
    text depth/.pgfmath={depth("Xpy")},
  },
  where level=0{}{
    if={n()==((n_children("!u")+1)/2)}{calign with current}{},
  },
  [+
    [+
      [Exp]
      [+]
      [Exp]
    ]
    [+]
    [Exp]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest solution]